# Could I use わたしのうちには　ペットが　いません 。instead of わたしのうえ に ペット は いません。

Tags: particle-に, particle-は

I've learned the expressions:

> (Location) の (position) には ありません/いません。 and
> (location) に (noun) は ありません/いません。

and I'm kinda wondering whether I could use には with location nouns too? Or does it only work for position nouns?

Could I use
わたしのうちには　ペットが　いません instead of わたしのうち に ペット は いません to express that my house doesn't have any pets?

Comment: In your second option (title and main body) you have うえ. I'm assuming you meant to type either うち or いえ but I'm not sure which. Please edit in your intended correction.

Comment: The whole noun phrase `(location) の (position)` *does* denote a location. So your sentence is fundamentally no different in structure from the first pattern you learned.

Comment: Sorry. I was supposed to type  うち

Comment: So i could count `(location) の (position)` as a noun phrase in Japanese and put that right in the second pattern directly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, both are correct, and the nuance is slight and not easily captured in English.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys